# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 6 column 11 path $.data

Tags: arrays, json, gson

i have json, and i want to retrieve using gson,below my json :

```
{
    "status_code":1,
    "message":"response ok",
    "api_version":"v1",
    "api_endpoint_name":"category_island",
    "data": [
        {
            "island_id":1,
            "island_name":"Anambas",
            "categories": [
                {"id":1, "category_name":"Culinary"},
                {"id":2, "category_name":"Hotel"},
                {"id":3, "category_name":"Culture"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

after that i create model to retrieve it :

```
public class ModelCategory {

    @SerializedName("status_code")
    public String status_code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("api_version")
    public String api_version;

    @SerializedName("api_endpoint_name")
    public String api_endpoint_name;

    @SerializedName("data")
    public data data;

    public static class data {

        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;
        @SerializedName("island_name")
        public String island_name;
        @SerializedName("categories")
        public List<categories> categories;

        public static class categories {

            @SerializedName("ID")
            public String id;
            @SerializedName("category_name")
            public String category_name;

        }

    }
}
```

and this is my code to retrieve json, i'm using gson:

```
ModelCategory model = new Gson().fromJson(models, ModelCategory.class);
ArrayList<ModelCategory.data.categories> _model = (ArrayList<ModelCategory.data.categories>) model.data.categories;
```

but when i run always display error in ModelCategory , error like below :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 6 column 11 path $.data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the model. Try this -

**Category.java**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Category {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("category_name")
    @Expose
    private String categoryName;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [id=" + id + ", categoryName=" + categoryName + "]";
    }
}
```

**Datum.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {
    @SerializedName("island_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer islandId;
    @SerializedName("island_name")
    @Expose
    private String islandName;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    public Integer getIslandId() {
        return islandId;
    }
    public void setIslandId(Integer islandId) {
        this.islandId = islandId;
    }
    public String getIslandName() {
        return islandName;
    }
    public void setIslandName(String islandName) {
        this.islandName = islandName;
    }
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Datum [islandId=" + islandId + ", islandName=" + islandName
                + ", categories=" + categories + "]";
    }
}
```

**Example.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer statusCode;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("api_version")
    @Expose
    private String apiVersion;
    @SerializedName("api_endpoint_name")
    @Expose
    private String apiEndpointName;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<Datum>();
    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getApiVersion() {
        return apiVersion;
    }
    public void setApiVersion(String apiVersion) {
        this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
    }
    public String getApiEndpointName() {
        return apiEndpointName;
    }
    public void setApiEndpointName(String apiEndpointName) {
        this.apiEndpointName = apiEndpointName;
    }
    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [statusCode=" + statusCode + ", message=" + message
                + ", apiVersion=" + apiVersion + ", apiEndpointName="
                + apiEndpointName + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }
}
```

Now you can test it as -

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.testgson.beans.Example;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{\"status_code\":1,\"message\":\"response ok\",\"api_version\":\"v1\",\"api_endpoint_name\":\"category_island\",\"data\":[{\"island_id\":1,\"island_name\":\"Anambas\",\"categories\":[{\"id\":1,\"category_name\":\"Culinary\"},{\"id\":2,\"category_name\":\"Hotel\"},{\"id\":3,\"category_name\":\"Culture\"}]}]}";
        Example info = gson.fromJson(s, Example.class);
        System.out.println(info);
   }
}
```

**Result is -**

```
Example [statusCode=1, message=response ok, apiVersion=v1, apiEndpointName=category_island, data=[Datum [islandId=1, islandName=Anambas, categories=[Category [id=1, categoryName=Culinary], Category [id=2, categoryName=Hotel], Category [id=3, categoryName=Culture]]]]]
```